# Find extreme values of ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, extreme-value-analysis

I have the curve equation

$$
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy = 1
$$

which represents ellipse with center in (0, 0) and rotated some angle.

[image]

How can I find max X and Y values (not semi-axes) on this ellipse? Points are marked on the picture.

There `x`-es and `y`-es can not be moved left or right side, so I cannot find `dx/dy` and `dy/dx`.

Comment: To find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\frac{dx}{dy}$ you can use implicit differentiation

Comment: Thanks for all, the all three ways leads to similar formulas. And thanks for reminding "implicit functions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given
$$
Ax^2  + Cxy + By^2  - 1 = 0
$$

solve for $x$ to get
$$
x = {{ - Cy \pm \sqrt {C^2 y^2  - 4A\left( {By^2  - 1} \right)} } \over {2A}}
$$

That means that fixing $y$ you get two solutions for $x$, until $y$ reaches the top (or lower) extreme
where the two solutions are coincident, i.e.
$$
\eqalign{
  & C^2 y^2  - 4A\left( {By^2  - 1} \right) = 0 \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \left( {C^2  - 4AB} \right)y^2  = -4A \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow y =  \pm \sqrt {{{-4A} \over {C^2  - 4AB}}}  \cr} 
$$

So
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  y_{extr}  =  \pm \sqrt {{{4A} \over {-C^2  + 4AB}}}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{extr.y}  =  - {C \over {2A}}y_{extr}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Then do the same in solving for $y$

Comment: Thanks for you answer and edit, i will test it tomorrow.

Comment: all right, and consider that the "zeroing of the discriminant" is an easy scheme to "frame" a curve between lines (vertical, horizontal or inclined): of course when the equation of the curve allows to easily solve for intersections.

Comment: y=±sqrt(-4A/(C^2-4AB))

Comment: @maestro : you are right sorry, typo amended

Answer (score 1):

I see two methods, both involving treating y as a function of x, to find the maximum and minimum values of y, then treating x as a function of y, to find the maximum and minimum values of x.

The simpler in calculation is to set the derivative equal to 0.

We can set the derivative of y with respect to x to 0.  With $Ax^2+ By^2+ Cxy= 1$ we have $2Ax+ 2By\frac{dy}{dx}+ Cy+ Cx\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$.  Setting $\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$, $2Ax+ Cy= 0$ so $y= -2\frac{A}{C}x$.  Putting that into $Ax^2+ By^2+ Cxy= 1$ we have $Ax^2+ 4\frac{A^2B}{C^2}x^2- 2Ax^2= \left(4\frac{A^2B}{C^2}- A\right)x^2= 1$.  $x= \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\frac{A^2B}{C^2}- A}}$ gives the x values for which y takes it maximum and minimum values.

Do the same treating x as a function of y to find the x values for which x takes it maximum and minimum values.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, use polar co-ordinates $x=r \cos t, y= r \sin t$ to get

$r^2(t)=\frac{1}{A \cos^2 t+ B\sin ^2 t+C \sin t \cos t}$

Let $u(t)=1/r^2(t)$ $\implies u(t)-\frac{A+B}{2}= \frac{A-B}{2} \cos 2t + \frac{c}{2}\sin 2t= \sqrt{\frac{(A-B)^2}{4}+\frac{c^2}{4}}~ \sin(2t+k)$
$\implies \frac{A+B}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{(A-B)^2}{4}+\frac{c^2}{4}}\le u(t) \le \frac{A+B}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{(A-B)^2}{4}+\frac{c^2}{4}}.$

From here one can get $r_{min}$ and $r_{max}$.